# Center and Scale a website using javascript

Tags: javascript, center

I am currently stuck in a technically simple problem, but since I want to support most of the browsers available it gets a bit complicated. I have content (HbbTV/CeHTML) which is always 1280x720, but the devices I try to present it can vary in the used resolution. I would like to rescale these pages on the resize Event.
Right now I do something like

```
document.body.style.transform = 'scale(' + window.innerWidth/1280 + ')';
  document.body.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';
```

This works, but does neither center the body, nor works if the user uses portrait mode. I like to fit the content to the view as best as possible and using only much instructions as necessary.

Looking forward for any advice.

I would like to get this primary working on Webkit based browsers, but if everything fails it should run also in IE9.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I would checkout [mcve]. Is there a reason why you can't just use CSS media queries? It seems like it would be rather simple using basic CSS media queries.

Comment: Yes, technically I inject the HbbTV implementation while reading the content from the server, I could do so with css too. I will give this a try.

Comment: I think you should just use `display: flex;` and it’s vendor prefixes. With the styles and other features you would need it should be supported by >97% of browsers.